# Error CRON for php script - DEBIAN

Tags: php, debian, cron

I have installed php5-cli to execute it from the shell

```
# aptitude update
# aptitude safe-upgrade
# aptitude install php5-cli
```

I edited the crontab

```
crontab -e
```

With this code

```
30 11 * * * (php5 /var/www/dreamteam/jobs/save_events_to_db.php) >> /var/www/dreamteam/logs/cron.log
```

I tested it manually

```
php5 /var/www/dreamteam/jobs/save_events_to_db.php
```

And it's OK

But the crontab didn't execut it. When I check the syslog

```
cat  cd /var/log/syslog
```

I have this error

```
(CRON) error (grandchild #7705 failed with exit status 255)
```

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Try running 'which php5' and use the full path to php - like `/usr/local/bin/php5 /var/www/dreamteam/jobs/save_events_to_db.php` in your crontab instead. And get rid of the parantheses.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/php5 doesn't exist...

Comment: I know - that was just an example. Thats why you should run 'which php5' as I said first and use the full path returned instead of what I gave as an example.

Comment: ok it works. But when i have errors on the php script it doesn't work.  ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Repox said above, you need to determine the full path to your PHP binary.
Typing "which php5" should give this to you.

Also if you want to redirect errors as well as normal output to your cron.log file, you should try adding "2>&1" at the end of the line.

This will redirect all standard errors to standard out (your cron.log file).

```
30 11 * * * (<path/to/php5> /var/www/dreamteam/jobs/save_events_to_db.php) >> /var/www/dreamteam/logs/cron.log 2>&1
```